# How do you create a dynamic page in Wordpress and not encounter issues with caching?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cloudflare

I am running a RoR website with a Wordpress blog and I have just implemented a logged in / logged out header in Wordpress using cookies that are set by the main (RoR) site when a user logs in.

Everything works fine except that when a user logs in or logs out (of the RoR site) I need to do a hard refresh on the wordpress site to see the modified header. I need to fix that.

My question is - *is this a problem with my caching settings, or should I have implemented the solution differently*?

**My solution**

My RoR website creates a cookie called 'login' when the user logs in and deletes that cookie when they log out.

I edited my child theme's `header.php` to insert this code:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['login'])) : ?>
  <!-- logged in header -->
<?php else : ?>
  <!-- not logged in header -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Caching**

I am using quite a few caching/optimisation plugins/services/settings including:

- Cloudflare
- WP Super Cache
- Autoptimze
- Apache config to set Cache-Control and Expires headings

Firstly, I disabled WP Super Cache because it appears its primary function is to cache HTML and PHP, and with the plugin active I need to delete the cache before the header will update with a hard refresh.

Then I unchecked the Autoptimze settings to disable cache of HTML.

Then I checked my Cloudflare settings - I am using Standard caching, using existing headers, and not doing any minification.

Finally my Apache config seems correct:

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 ...
     <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php|pdf)$">
       Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
     </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
```

As an additional test, I accessed the website directly (via the IP address) and this seems to work fine. I also ran some tests with "disable cache" ticked on the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools, and that also worked great.

Therefore I think the issue is now with Chrome.

When I look at the HTTP request headers, after returning to the Wordpress site after logging out or in, I see this:

```
Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)
```

And when I click the browser refresh button, the page refreshes and the header is correct.

Here are the HTTP response headers when the incorrect header is shown:

```
cache-control: private, must-revalidate
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 593e0b2e0cc706c5-LHR
cf-request-id: 02baa550c6000006c5e7912200000001
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 15 May 2020 15:55:31 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Fri, 15 May 2020 16:05:30 GMT
link: <https://www.example.com/blog/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
server: cloudflare
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Here are the HTTP response headers when I press the browser refresh button:

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/blog/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.27.165.96:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cache-control: private, must-revalidate
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 593e10d669ca06c5-LHR
cf-request-id: 02baa8da04000006c5e7896200000001
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 15 May 2020 15:59:22 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Fri, 15 May 2020 16:09:22 GMT
link: <https://www.example.com/blog/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
server: cloudflare
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
:authority: www.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /blog/
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-ZA,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check; __cfduid=dc19950d1c3d6d8e54fefd2b87c81a1e71589464189; _ga=GA1.2.1235735685.1589464190; _gid=GA1.2.1339832334.1589464190; _hjid=3f0fe3a6-cb06-4d37-886f-0358763f067e; _omappvp=Mhy6L4AKmb5TVpPhcNdtRDjwoZyTAfz7srbL1nfNUhhH7T6zyUjp3DYhWoOTp3vaiLL7tFM8xPRzCSb3KKuxM0xkiNhsOfS1; _fbp=fb.1.1589464195337.1508307578; intercom-id-qe94ii0z=b3b88868-e461-4624-a6aa-9c4b0ef77e76; _hjIncludedInSample=1; om-700710=true; editing=viewed; _gaexp=GAX1.2.R8_xwTncQfCHf-7lseMIpQ.18441.1!I2ThxUMmSpOQ2bSwIUXW-g.18445.0; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=1; intercom-session-qe94ii0z=S1dLWUcvTUdEdldSeEJXOEdJOURZVW02cDBkdWROZ2tEMWZPekZxV2llSTJRSTlxQVNhVW5BODdCMUFuK2NwSC0tM1o2QTdDbHFxMklja0l4TTFpOXlMZz09--29bdb35de1443e4d7dbe4c5f56289131b74e2b36; _gat=1; _example_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiJWJkYmJlMTM4NmE3ODg0YmY5ZjdlYTZjM2E2Y2M1ZWY4BjsAVEkiCmZsYXNoBjsAVHsHSSIMZGlzY2FyZAY7AFRbBkkiCmFsZXJ0BjsARkkiDGZsYXNoZXMGOwBUewZADEkiNllvdSBuZWVkIHRvIHNpZ24gaW4gb3Igc2lnbiB1cCBiZWZvcmUgY29udGludWluZy4GOwBUSSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4GOwBGSSIxU2tRY1N6LzFSMGx2RGFlQ1BNMzgzZHBCQ1FIL3AxK2prd0NobmZaZ1Z1dz0GOwBGSSITdXNlcl9yZXR1cm5fdG8GOwBUIhUvZGFzaGJvYXJkL2luZGV4--242e9a815510fe910d3372b5b9e2ef8bc8f800e4
referer: https://www.example.com/users/sign_in
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: A couple of questions; what's being modified in the header? And also, when you say 'logout' are they logging out of the WordPress site or the RoR application? My initial guess would be, that if the logout is within the RoR that the cookie itself is possibly what's cached.

Comment: Yes, logout is from the RoR website - the Wordpress site is just a blog (I'll change my question to make that clear). 

The cookie is not cached because I can see that it is removed in Chrome Dev Tools. 

I'm not modifying the request headers - the two sets of response headers referenced in my question are from the cached page and then when I reload the page.

Comment: I'm trying to related this back to an issue I had in the past.  I'm wondering if it would help to set states for the cookie and then run your conditional statement based on whether it's 'true' or 'false'.  That may then force the browser to do that extra check which could ensure that it's loading the most correct version.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean setting a boolean value on the cookie and check that value instead of just checking the cookie exists? I use another cookie already (that stores the name of the user) and reading the data from that cookie is not forcing the page to be refreshed. Interesting idea though, thanks.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking yes.  Sorry if it doesn’t work. I’ve been using managed servers for the past 4 years so it’s been a while since I looked at a lot of this stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help @TonyDjukic ... I'll update the ticket when I find out the answer - at this point I suspect it's Cloudflare

Comment: I finally solved my problem - which turned out to be Apache. I have posted an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to debug this problem using `wget` on the server like so:

```
$ wget https://localhost/blog/ --no-check-certificate --server-response
```

Once I disabled the two plugins I was using for caching in Wordpress, this command allowed me to bypass Cloudflare and see the headers being set by Apache.

```
--2020-05-19 13:21:08--  https://localhost/blog/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify localhost's certificate, issued by ‘ST=California,L=San Francisco,OU=CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority,O=CloudFlare\\, Inc.,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
WARNING: no certificate subject alternative name matches
    requested host name ‘localhost’.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 19 May 2020 12:21:08 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Link: <https://localhost/blog/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
  Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
  Expires: Tue, 19 May 2020 12:31:08 GMT
  Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

I noticed that the Cache-Control header was different to the one in my Apache configuration.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

This was because the Cache-Control header was being set in the root domain Apache config but not for the blog (it is being hosted with a reverse proxy).

The solution was to copy all the Expires and Cache-Control header config into my blog Apache configuration file and then voila:

```
$ wget https://localhost/blog/ --no-check-certificate --server-response--2020-05-19 16:41:19--  https://localhost/blog/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify localhost's certificate, issued by ‘ST=California,L=San Francisco,OU=CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority,O=CloudFlare\\, Inc.,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
WARNING: no certificate subject alternative name matches
    requested host name ‘localhost’.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 19 May 2020 15:41:20 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie,User-Agent
  Link: <https://localhost/blog/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
  Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
  Expires: Tue, 19 May 2020 15:41:20 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

For completeness, please see my new Apache config for my blog:

```
# avoids sending hackers too much info about the server
ServerTokens Prod

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAdmin dagmar@example.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/blog/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/blog/access.log common

  DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
  <Directory /var/www/blog>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>

  # Enable Compression
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent
  </IfModule>

  # Enable expires headers
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                    "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html                     "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/plain                    "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml           "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml          "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType text/x-component              "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 0 seconds"
  </IfModule>

  # Enable caching headers
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     # Calculate etag on modified time and file size (could be turned off too ?)
     FileETag MTime Size
     # NEVER CACHE - notice the extra directives
     <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
       Header set Cache-Control "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
     </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
```